# Can NPOI Mapper set the row number

Tags: c#, npoi

I'm currently using npoi.mapper in c# to read an excel file into poco classes for further processing and it is all working very well.

The system has grown and several spreadsheets are often processed in parrallel I would thefore like to include the filename and row number in my poco class to use for debugging purposes.

So far I've just added the filename and row number in by hand in a for loop but was wondering if I could refactor & clean up my code by having npoi.mapper do this for me?

heres my code:

```
   var mapper = new Mapper(excelStream);
   var rows = mapper.Take<MyPocoClass>("Sheet2");

   for(int i = 0; i < rows.Length; i++)
   {
       var row = rows[i];

       row.Filename = excelName;
       row.RowNumber = i;
   }
```

I've read the documentation over on the [GitHub Page](https://github.com/donnytian/Npoi.Mapper) and it sounds like I should be using a custom resolver, but I cannot see how to access the row number as part of that?

Comment: Can you share how you map the columns of excel to your MyPocoClass?

Comment: @LuttiCoelho  its convention based - I use a POCO class with properties which have the same name as the column headings (row 1) on "Sheet2" of the workbook.  NPOI mapper does the rest - its really very clever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take a look at the [Mapper.cs](https://github.com/donnytian/Npoi.Mapper/blob/develop/Npoi.Mapper/src/Npoi.Mapper/Mapper.cs) on github and I realized that the [RowInfo](https://github.com/donnytian/Npoi.Mapper/blob/develop/Npoi.Mapper/src/Npoi.Mapper/RowInfo.cs) and [IRowInfo](https://github.com/donnytian/Npoi.Mapper/blob/develop/Npoi.Mapper/src/Npoi.Mapper/IRowInfo.cs) classes (That holds the row number) are only used on returns of the public methods.

On the extensions folder I found an ExtensionMethod of `IEnumerable<T>` called `ForEach<T>` at class  [EnumerableExtensions](https://github.com/donnytian/Npoi.Mapper/blob/develop/Npoi.Mapper/src/Npoi.Mapper/Extensions/EnumerableExtensions.cs) that could be used as an alternative for your current code.

This is a non tested solution.

```
   var mapper = new Mapper(excelStream);
   var rows = mapper.Take<MyPocoClass>("Sheet2");

   rows.Foreach<RowInfo<MyPocoClass>>(row => {
        row.Value.Filename = "Sheet2";
        row.Value.RowNumber = row.RowNumber;
   });
```

This is just a sintatic sugar for your current code.

---

In my opinion the best approach for that kind of job would fllow this steps:

1) Create an interface or a base type that contains the properties `Filename` and `RowNumber`. Ex of base type:

```
public class MyPocoFromExcelBase 
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public int RowNumber { get; set; }
}
```

2) Inherit `MyPocoFromExcelBase` on your `MyPocoClass` and any other class that represents a row from an excel file.

3) Create a Extension Method for `IEnumerable<RowInfo<MyPocoFromExcelBase>>` and do the mapping:

```
    public static void MapRowNumber(this IEnumerable<RowInfo<MyPocoFromExcelBase>> sequence, string fileName)
    {
        if (sequence == null) return;

        foreach (var item in sequence)
        {
            item.Value.Filename = fileName;
            item.Value.RowNumber = item.RowNumber;
        }
    }
```

4) Then you can do something like this in any mapper:

```
var mapper = new Mapper(excelStream);
var rows = mapper.Take<MyPocoClass>("Sheet2");
rows.MapRowNumber("Sheet2");
```

This way you will not need to rewrite this logic all over your code.

Comment: Hi thanks, for your answer.  Overall it is a bit neater at the cost of introducing a base class (or interface).  I'm going to wait to see if I get any more response before awarding answer.  Also where does row.RowNumber come from in your extension method?

Comment: Hi @Twisted, you are welcome. No problem, I'll be glad to up vote any answer that give you a better approach.

Comment: row.RowNumber was a error. I already fix it. The correct is item.RowNumber as it is a property of RowInfo class.

Comment: Hi @Twisted. Have you tested my solution? Did it help you?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a quick solution, add Id field to YourItemDTO, then you can do:

```
var report = mapper.Take<YourItemDTO>()
    .Select((item, index) => { item.Value.Id = index; return item.Value; })
    .ToList();
```